# Zeppelin cannot read file path of local file System

Tags: apache-spark, docker, apache-zeppelin

I have installed Zeppelin with Docker on my Windows System, Now I am trying run the code as defined in [Zeppelin Tutorial](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/quickstart/tutorial.html#tutorial-with-local-file) with local file but it is throwing error -

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected scheme-specific part at index 2: C:
at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
at java.net.URI$Parser.failExpecting(URI.java:2854)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3057)
at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:746)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:203)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:172)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:94)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.glob(Globber.java:201)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:1643)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:222)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:270)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:194)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
```

Here is the path I am using-

> file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/bank/bank-full.csv

Code-

```
val bankText = sc.textFile("file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/bank/bank-full.csv")

case class Bank(age:Integer, job:String, marital : String, education : String, balance : Integer)

val bank = bankText.map(s=>s.split(";")).filter(s=>s(0)!="\"age\"").map(
s=>Bank(s(0).toInt, 
        s(1).replaceAll("\"", ""),
        s(2).replaceAll("\"", ""),
        s(3).replaceAll("\"", ""),
        s(5).replaceAll("\"", "").toInt
    )
 )

 bank.toDF().registerTempTable("bank")
 %sql select * from bank
```

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show a piece of your code? Because for me it just works with `new URI(...);`

Comment: Please check the question again. @AlexOtt

Comment: It's really something strange with Hadoop - it looks like that it first transform URI, and then pass the transformed string to `java.net.URI` constructor... Unfortunately I don't know answer

Answer (score 0):

Use file:///xampp/htdocs/bank/bank-full.csv
And make sure your program are also in C driver.

Comment: My programme inside Docker and Path is - `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual hard disks`, I tried your solution, it says `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/xampp/htdocs/bank/bank-full.csv` :( @zjffdu